# Do not select text anywhere between double square brackets

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need to write an regex that is matching something according to pattern (and that works), but if the text is anywhere inside double squared brackets it shouldn't match it.
The actual problem is that negative lookbehind can't be variable length.

The case is:

- There is a dictionary of phrases.
- Phrases with more word are "stronger"/got priority over phrases with shorter words.
- Some of phrases are parts of other longer phrases.

Example dictionary (sorted like an array in real code):

```
Wooden House
House
Wooden
```

Example text to be parsed:

```
Lorem ipsum Wooden House dolor sit amet
```

Parsing is done via preg_replace on text to be parsed done by iterating through a dictionary and adding `[[randomstaff-_-current dictionary phrase]]`, so for example:

`Lorem ipsum Wooden House dolor sit amet` -> `Lorem ipsum [[randomstuff-_-Wooden House]] dolor sit amet`.

currently after the second iteration it becomes:
`Lorem ipsum [[randomstuff-_-Wooden House]] dolor sit amet` -> `Lorem ipsum [[randomstuff-_-Wooden[[randomstuff-_-House]]]]`

and I would want to left it unchanged if it's already between `[[` and `]]`.

So basically if match is **anywhere** between `[[` and `]]` - ignore it.

```
$dictPhrases = ["Wooden House", "House", "Wooden"];
$TEXT = "Lorem ipsum Wooden House dolor sit amet";

for ($dictPhrases as $phrase){
 $phraseOccurences = 0; //irrelevant in this example
 $TEXT = preg_replace("/(?i)(?<= |^|\n)(" . $phrase. "[&()'-]{0,1})(?= |$|\.|\,)/", "[[$randomstuff-_-" . $phrase . "]]", $TEXT, -1, $phraseOccurences);

}
```

The question is how to change:

```
/(?i)(?<= |^|\n)(" . $phrase. "[&()'-]{0,1})(?= |$|\.|\,)/
```

into something like:

```
/(?i)(?<!\[\[.*)(?<= |^|\n)(" . $phrase. "[&()'-]{0,1})(?= |$|\.|\,)(?!.*\]\])/
```

to see if matched phrase is not between `[[` and `]]` and discard it if it is.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking about this the wrong way... Try getting the 1st iteration into different parts.  Then on the second iteration, you can manipulate to the string from the second iteration with the parts of the first iteration.  So for example your phrase from the iteration can used to do a string_replace(PHRASE_ONE, '', $secondIteration);  Then process the regex on the parts of the string that are left for the second iteration.  Once that has been processed, break that up, and process the third the way you did for the second.  Repeat until its done.  Map it all back together at the end.

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you describe - since the replacement only takes place if optionally `&()'-` and mandatorily ` $\.\,` follow the phrase, `House` followed by `]` isn't replaced in the second iteration. You should align the code with your description.

Comment: @Armali there is a space in both positives (lookbehind and lookahead).
`(?<=<space here>|^|\n)...(?=<space here>|$|\.|\,)`

Comment: I'm well aware of the space, and that has nothing to do with what I wrote. Try the code you posted and you'll see that it _doesn't do what you describe_.

Answer (score 0):

Just transform

```
["Wooden House", "House", "Wooden"]
```

into a single regular expression:

```
"(?:Wooden House|House|Wooden)"
```

and then put it into the main regex.

Try with something like this:

```
$dictPhrases = ["Wooden House", "House", "Wooden"];
$TEXT = "Lorem ipsum Wooden House dolor sit amet";

$pattern = "/(?i)(?<= |^|\n)((?:" . join('|', $dictPhrases) . ")[&()'-]{0,1})(?= |$|\.|\,)/";

$phraseOccurences = preg_match_all($pattern, $TEXT);
$TEXT = preg_replace($pattern, "[[$randomstuff-_-$1]]", $TEXT);
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/0OB9YL/1) a regex demo.

[Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8567868eed43ebd30cf7f2f571226928c4af1ee1) a PHP demo.

Comment: Unfortunately unapplicable.
This way I cannot match that randompart to certain dictionary entry - it's out of for loop :/

But I'll try to use it with assoc array with pregenerated random part as keys and dict entries as values.
Gonna post code if it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably got two solutions for that.

1) Get starting position of match, find all "[[" and "]]" in substring(0, first char of  match) and mod them by 2.
2) Get starting position of match, get last position of "[[" and last position of "]]" in substring(0, first char of match) and check which one is closer.

Both should work within the assumption that brackets can't be nested (which is true in this particular case).
Unfortunately the code needed is out of regex capabilities.

I'll try to implement it on Monday and post final code for future seekers - if it will work as intended ofc.